# Operator $Lu = \sum_j A_j \partial_{x_j} u$.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have an operator: $L=\sum_j A_j \partial_{x_j} $, where $A_j$ is a symmetric square matrix whose entries are smooth functions; i.e $A_j = A_j^*$.

Is it true that $L=L^*$.

If I compute I get:

$$(Lu,v) = \int \sum_j A_j (\partial_j u) v dx$$

$$ (L^*u,v)=\int \sum_j A_j (\partial_j v) u dx$$

So it doesn't seem that $L$ is self-adjoint to it self.

Comment: what is the question? $u$ is vecotr valued?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: @QinfengLi , I need to show that somehow that $(Lw(s) , w(t)) \le C\| w(s) \|_{L^2} \| w(t)\|_{L^2}$, by some positive constant $C$, where the integration is being done on a compact manifold such as the torus, $\mathbb{T}^n$.